# How to place a text as a overlay on a image vertically aligned to top left in a div

Tags: html, css

With the below code, why does the COMING SOON text going further to right and not getting aligned to left. The text has to be placed as an overlay vertically at the top left corner of the image

***HTML:***

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="badge">NEW</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="badge">SALE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="badge">COMING SOON</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.grid{display:block;width:100%;}
.block{width:255px;height:255px;border:1px solid #333;margin:12px;float:left;position:relative;}
.badge{position:absolute;transform:rotate(90deg);top:12px;left:0;}
```

Comment: please create any working demo or fiddle where we can see the issue..thanx

Comment: I want the text to be vertically placed, Solution would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by vertically placed? Please give an example...

Comment: PFB the JSFiddle link, https://jsfiddle.net/m6v8ttpk/.... Here the COMING SOON text is moving towards the right side and i want it to be placed to the top left corner of the block. As the text size increases the text slides towards the right side, this is the issue

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/neaqd0sm/

Comment: The problem is, I also want a background image for class '.block' which should not be rotated vertically, I just want the text to be rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform-origin`. It says to the browser around which point should `transform: rotate` happen.

Find code at: http://jsfiddle.net/yv0Lugp8/1/

More info on transform-origin can be found [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

EDIT: Changed url after updating code.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the `transform:rotate(90deg)` to the .block class like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tudf7cqL/).
Also change the `top` property for the `.badge` to be `230px`.

CSS:

```
.grid{display:block;width:100%;}
.block{transform:rotate(90deg);width:255px;height:255px;border:1px solid #333;margin:12px;float:left;position:relative;}
.badge{position:absolute;top:230px;left:0;}
```

Comment: The text within the badge class is getting rotated, but the issue is with the 'COMING SOON' text, as the text length increases the text slides towards the right side.

PFB the link,
https://jsfiddle.net/m6v8ttpk/

Comment: well that's really fast..upvoted your answer(like me :p) :)

Comment: make that position bottom : 5px; it will work great dont need top and left

Comment: @imGaurav, check my fiddle in comment.but op is not getting out point.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tranform-orgin` is wrong (actually lack thereof.)

See the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/tvwkwx9r/)

The following is the relevant CSS

```
.badge {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    left: 14px;
}
```

I also shifted `.badge` left by 14px to offset `.block` 12px margin and 1px border. I added `float: left` to `.badge` as well. See this [**ARTICLE**](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text)

Comment: Hey Thanks... This did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

The [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property will help you here . 
By default i reckon the transform origin is at centre of your '.badge' element, so the text moves away from the '.block' element when rotated by 90 deg.

Try changing your 'badge' class as below :

```
.badge {
    position:absolute;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin:0px 15px;
    top:12px;
    left:0;
}
```

You may want to move  around values to accomodate to your liking.